# Create XML Tree from Hierarchy Levels and Text

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have a text file with hierarchy levels and text like this:

```
1 A
2 B
2 C
3 D
3 E
2 F
1 G
```

and I want to create an XML document like this:

```
<A>
  <B></B>
  <C>
    <D></D>
    <E></E>
  </C>
  <F></F>
</A>
<G></G>
```

Is there a python library that does this job?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic. Add your tries at solving it and errors that happen as [mcve]

Comment: Asking for a library may be off topic. I added a possible solution that might be usefu for other people having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found an answer myself.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class item:
""" class to hold level and tag """
    def __init__(self, line):
        __s_list = (line.split(' ', 1))
        if len(__s_list) != 2:
            raise Exception("Invalid list length: " + str(len(__s_list)) + " at " + line)
        self.level = int(__s_list[0])
        self.tag = __s_list[1].lstrip()

# Read infile and put items into list
list = []
with open(path + "sample.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        list.append(item(line))

root = ET.Element("root")
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

# Create list to hold last parent per level
last_parents = []
last_parents[0] = root

for element in list:
    # extend last_parents if necessary
    if len(last_parents) <= element.level + 1:
    last_parents.append[None]
    # insert element into tree and save it in last_parents
    last_parents[element.level] =  ET.SubElement(last_parents[element.level-1], element.tag)
    print(str(element.level) + ": "+ element.tag)

tree.write(path+"sample.xml")
```

Gives:

```
<root>
    <A>
        <B />
        <C>
            <D />
            <E />
        </C>
        <F />
    </A>
    <G  />
</root>
```